# I need to set a select to selected using data-val

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a select I need to set to selected but the select is using a name and the options are using "data-val" and I can't change either:

```
<select name="properties[Liner]">
<option data-val="1">Option 1</option>
<option data-val="2">Option 2</option>
<option data-val="3">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

How can I set Option 2 to selected using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple ways that you could go about this;

You could be *very* explicit and set the value of the `<select />` itself through;

```
document.querySelector('[name="properties[Liner]"]').value = "Option 2";
```

Or you could be a *little* bit more dynamic with the following;

```
document.querySelector('[name="properties[Liner]"]').value = document.querySelector('[data-val="2"]').value;
```

- For the targeting of the name, you'll want to use `[name="{some name}"]`
- For the targeting of a data-attribute, you'll want to use `[data-val="{some value}"]`

In this scenario, you could just specify "name" for `querySelector` and you'll get what you want because there's only one element with a name on the page (at least in your mini-scenario).

Answer (score 0):

Code explanation in comments

```js
(function(){
const selectEle = document.querySelector('[name="properties[Liner]"]'); // query the select the element
const setSelected = 2; // set the default value
const options = selectEle.querySelectorAll('option'); // query all the option element
options.forEach((option)=>{
   const value = option.getAttribute('data-val'); // get the attribute data-val
   if(value == setSelected){ // if matches
     option.setAttribute('selected', true);  // set selected
   }
});


})();
```

```html
<select name="properties[Liner]">
<option data-val="1">Option 1</option>
<option data-val="2">Option 2</option>
<option data-val="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```